# regex to extract version info

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have written a small Python function to extract version info from a string.
Input is of format:

- v{Major}.{Minor}[b{beta-num}]

Eg: v1.1, v1.10b100, v1.100b01
Goal is to extract Major, Minor and beta numbers.

```
import re
def VersionInfo(x):
    reg = re.compile('^v([0-9]+)([.])([0-9]+)(b)?([0-9]+)?$')
    return reg.findall(x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(VersionInfo('v1.01b10'))
    print(VersionInfo('v1.01'))
    print(VersionInfo('v1.0'))
```

Output:

```
[('1', '.', '01', 'b', '10')]
[('1', '.', '01', '', '')]
[('1', '.', '0', '', '')]
```

Question is:

- Is it sufficient to cover all cases?
- Better regex?

Comment: Is `v1.1b` valid? (i.e. beta with no beta number)

Comment: No. But howto handle it?

Comment: Do you need to capture the `b` and `.` as well?

Comment: Is it intentional that you are ignoring the micro version and most release levels? If not then there are a few versions that your regex won't work with: 3.5.1f0 (3.5.1), 2.1.0b1, 2.2.0a1.

Comment: I have just assumed that my input will only contain major and minor versions and beta versions only. This was easy to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Compile your regexp only once. Doing it each time you call `VersionInfo` kind of defeat its purpose. You can extract it out of the function and give it a proper capitalized name to indicate it is a constant.
- Use blank lines to separate logical sections of your code, especially after `import`s and before functions definition.
- According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), function names should be *snake_case* and not *TitleCase*.

Answer (score 8):

```
^v([0-9]+)([.])([0-9]+)(b)?([0-9]+)?$
```

Not much to say but:

- seems a bit strange to capture the `.` since that's the only value that could be there. Also `[.]` could be written mode simply as `\.`.
- also seems a bit strange to capture the `b`, unless `v1.1b` is specifically allowed. And you're trying to find that last digit group even if `b` isn't present - not a bug, but could be made clearer.

To address the second point, make the whole beta part optional:

```
^v([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(?:(b)([0-9]+)?)?$
```

If beta with no number isn't allowed, this can be simplified (and drop capturing `b` also in this case):

```
^v([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(?:b([0-9]+))?$
```

(The `(?:...)` construct is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).)

Comment: Note that if you want to have `\.` in the regex, then it would be a good idea to use `r'raw strings'`.

Comment: Point noted on the capture of "." which is not required.

Comment: Interesting: non-capturing group . I didn't know that. I will read into it.

Comment: You might also mention that `\d` is shorter than `[0-9]`.

Comment: @zondo: `\d` is shorter, but not 100% equivalent on all regex engines/modes - can match more than `0-9` if in Unicode mode.

Answer (score 5):

I’d suggest using [*named capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and *non-capturing groups* to improve the regex – you only get relevant information, and it makes it easier to access the attributes later.

For example:

```
VERSION_REGEX = re.compile(
    r'^'                        # start of string
    r'v'                        # literal v character
    r'(?P<major>[0-9]+)'        # major number
    r'\.'                       # literal . character
    r'(?:.(?P<minor>[0-9+]))'   # minor number
    r'(?:b(?P<beta>[0-9+]))?'   # literal b character, and beta number
)
```

The `?P<name>` means that we can access this attribute by name in a match. (*named*)
The `?:` at the start of a group means its value is ignored. (*non-capturing*)

*Note:* The `b` for beta is now part of a non-capturing group, which contains the `beta` capturing group. This means that the regex will only get the `b` if it’s followed by a number; it wouldn’t for example, match `v1.0b`. (Which seems to be the desired behaviour, from the comments.)

This gives us the following, IMO nicer-to-work-with output:

```
versions = ['v1.01b10', 'v1.01', 'v1.0']

for version_str in versions:
    match = VERSION_REGEX.search(version_str)
    print match.groupdict()

# {'major': '1', 'minor': '01', 'beta': '10'}
# {'major': '1', 'minor': '01', 'beta': None}
# {'major': '1', 'minor': '0', 'beta': None}
```

Some more minor points:

- I’ve broken up the regex across multiple lines, with liberal comments to explain what’s going on. Although this is a fairly simple regex, I think this is good practice. It makes them substantially easier to work with, long-term.
- I’ve prefixed my string with `r`. This is a raw string, which means I have to do slightly less work when escaping backslashes and the like. Again, perhaps not necessary in this case, but a good habit to get into.
- Since your regex binds to the start of the string, `findall()` will only ever get one match. You’d be better off using something like `search()`, which returns SREMatch objects instead of tuples. This gives you, for example, the nice named-group semantics I used above.
- Function names should be lowercase_with_underscores, not CamelCase. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- Compile the regex once as a constant at the top of your file, not every time you call the function. This is more efficient.
- Whitespace (more newlines) will help break up your code and make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose an alternate solution that just captures the version numbers themselves. If you need the `b` and `.` as legitimate capture groups, this solution might not work for you.

```
    REG = re.compile('[.bv]')
def VersionInfo(x):
    return re.split(REG, x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(VersionInfo('v1.01b10'))
    print(VersionInfo('v1.01'))
    print(VersionInfo('v1.01b'))
    print(VersionInfo('v1.0'))
```

This gives the following result:

```
['', '1', '01', '10']
['', '1', '01']
['', '1', '01', '']
['', '1', '0']
```

As you can see, this only captures the numbers themselves, the Regex is far easier to read and if the 4th group is there, but empty, your version number has a `b` without a beta number, which is what you said you want to handle in a comment.

One thing I'm not sure about is if the datatype that's returned is equally usable.

Comment: Nice and short regex. Thx.